# Using "file_fixture" in before(:suite)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to do this in the `spec_helper`:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  allow(Net::HTTP)
    .to receive(:get)
    .with(URI(some_uri))
    .and_return(file_fixture('response.json').read)
end
```

But unfortunately this is not working:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `file_fixture' for #<RSpec::Core::AnonymousExampleGroup (no description provided)>
```

But when I do this:

```
config.before(:each) do
...
end
```

it works?

Why is this so and is it possible to use `file_fixture` also in a `before(:suite)` block?

Answer (score 0):

`file_fixture` apparently is available only at the example level. It means that you can use it inside `it` or `specify` or inside `let` blocks.

What it does - it's just a simple helper to read files, you can probably fix it this way:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  allow(Net::HTTP)
    .to receive(:get)
    .with(URI(some_uri))
    .and_return(File.read('path/to/your/fixtures/response.json'))
end
```